# Parameters for register_setting()

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am a little confused with the parameters. Option name is the actual name of the added settings field, but what is the option group? Is this the same name we use in add_option()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A settings group name. This must match the group name used in register_setting(), which is the page slug name on which the form is to appear.
Check it here https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API#Options_Form_Rendering

Comment: So the option group will always be the page slug where the settings will apear?